# phpの日付解釈

Tags: php

この形式の日付データをphpのstrtotimeで解釈させたいのですが
どのように書くのが適切でしょうか？

曜日, 日 月 年 時:分:秒 時差

例 ) 水, 02 01 2015 01:00:00 +09:00

Comment: [phpのドキュメント](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.strtotime.php)には「 **英文形式** の日付を Unix タイムスタンプに変換する」とあるので不可能です。

Comment: この文字列は人間が見ても解釈できないと思いますが。他の要素から察するに、11が月、31は日付のようですが、11月31日という日は存在していません。まず、この文字列の解釈の仕方を説明していただく必要があるかと思います。

Comment: 以下のURLに似たような質問がありました。

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668223/php-date-parse-from-format-alternative-in-php-5-2

Comment: 曜日が日付の解釈というのは難しいようなので、sken2さんから頂いた回答で、曜日部分をランダムなバイト列として解釈させることで、実行できました。

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

日付データを基にunix epochtimeを求めたいというなら以下でできます。

```
$theday = 'Mon, 11 30 2015 10:00:22 +0900';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, n j Y H:i:s T', $theday);
$epoch = $dt->format('U');
var_dump( $epoch);
```

ただ、自分のテスト環境ではロケールの設定がおかしいのか、曜日の'月'は受け付けてくれませんでした。
3番目の項目は31から30に変更しました。
要素のフォーマットについては、ゼロが付くのかサンプルから判断できないものはこちらで勝手に選びました。詳細は
http://php.net/manual/ja/datetime.createfromformat.php
を参照してください。